Installing Gimp-devel on arch linux: could not find all required packages: gegl >=0.4.52
When I run yay to upgrade my system I run into this:
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 community is up to date
 multilib is up to date
:: Searching AUR for updates...
 -> No AUR package found for gegl>=0.4.52

...

:: 1 packages to upgrade/install.
1  aur/gimp-devel            3.0.0rc1-1 -> 3.0.0rc2-1
==> Packages to exclude: (eg: "1 2 3", "1-3", "^4" or repo name)
 -> Excluding packages may cause partial upgrades and break systems
==> 
 -> could not find all required packages: gegl >=0.4.52

I am on fully updated Arch linux. How can I resolve this issue?

gegl=0.4.52-1 is in extra-testing repo

Probably you can install gegl-git from the AUR. This package is listed as dependency of gimp-devel.
It's not clear to me how yay is supposed to find the version in AUR git packages. Look at the gegl-git PKGBUILD. The version is 0.4.49.r10849.d540df2ad but it will be updated with the pkgver function.
If you go trough the dependencies of the gimp-devel pkgbuild you find many other packages that can break the same way. To be safe you have to install all of them from AUR. In this case there are too many of them. It is easier to keep in mind that you might have to check the dependencies if you cannot upgrade gimp-devel.
